# JMS MockTopic message not picked up by message listener?

Tags: java, jms, mockrunner

I am trying to write a jUnit test to show that a **JMS** Subscriber's **start()** function kicks off the message listener for a **Topic** (and that messages were not being consumed before **start()** was called).

I am running into an issue where messages placed on the Topic before the **start()** function is called are not processed once **start()** is called. Messages placed on the Topic after **start()** is called are processed immediately.

```java
MockTopic topicWriter = getMockTopic(TOPIC);

// publish a message for the listener to pick up
MockObjectMessage objectMessage = new MockObjectMessage(message);
objectMessage.setBooleanProperty("Broadcast", true);

topicWriter.addMessage(objectMessage);

// the message doesn't get consumed because the subscriber has not been started
//...assert that the message is not processed... (**SUCCEEDS**)

// start the subscriber/listener
subscriber.start();

//...assert that the messages sitting on the topic get processed... (**FAILS**)

// publish a message for the listener to pick up
topicWriter.addMessage(objectMessage);

//...assert that the message gets processed... (**SUCCEEDS**)
```

While this shows that the listener is not running before **start()**, kicking off the message listener should cause all messages currently on the Topic to be processed.

I've attempted to make sure that persistency wasn't the cause by adding:

```java
    objectMessage.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
```

but this did not help.

Actually running the program seems to indicate that messages currently residing on the **Topic** are processed on **start()**. Does anyone know why the messages currently on the **MockTopic** might not be getting processed at **start()**? Is it a limitation of **MockTopic**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally clear if this is a MockTopic issue, but with respect to standard JMS, you would not expect a started listener to receive messages published before it started unless it was a *durable* subscription. The persistence is neither here nor there.

Comment: That is a very good point. I am not sure that it is an issue for this particular test, but it's worth looking into. The actual subscription is set to be durable but I am uncertain if that carries over into the test properly.